# SQL Get amount paid in statement account in different dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this schema

**Item**:

```
| ItemId | Name  | Price |
|--------|-------|-------|
|   1    |  Item1|  5.00 |
|   2    |  Item2|  2.00 |
```

**OrderHeader**:

```
| OrderId| OrderNum| OrderDate  |
|--------|---------|------------|
|   1    | ORD1    | 2017-05-10 |
|   2    | ORD2    | 2017-05-12 |
```

**OrderDetails**:

```
|OrderId| ItemId |  Total |
--------|--------|---------
|   1   |      1 |     3  |
|   2   |      1 |     2  |
```

How can I get this result:

```
|ItemId | OrderId   |  Paid  | Debt |
--------|-----------|----------------
|   1   | 1         |     3  |   2  |
|   1   | 2         |     5  |   0  |
```

In the result set, the column paid must contains the total of previous payments and plus the new one.

How can I use a Common table expression for example to solve this?

Comment: Where do you get paid and debt?

Comment: It's my statement account, for example, there are two payments (OrderDetails) for Item 1, with amounts of 3 and 2, so in the result, in the first row Paid is equals to 3 and Debt is equals to ItemPrice - Paid. In the second row, Paid is the new amount in OrderDetails (2) plus previous paid amount (3) equals to 5.

Comment: And row2 debt is row 1 debt - row2 paid?

Comment: Is ItemPrice -  row2 Paid

Answer (score 0):

This, you should have provided us:

```
  DECLARE @Item TABLE (Id int, [Name] varchar(15), Price int)
  DECLARE @OrderDetails TABLE (OrderId int, ItemId int, Total int)
  INSERT INTO @ITEM VALUES (1, 'ITEM1', 5), (2, 'ITEM2', 2)
  INSERT INTO @OrderDetails VALUES (1, 1, 3), (2, 1, 2)
```

This, seems to work, and I think it still has room for improvement:

```
SELECT OrderId, ItemId, [SUM1], R.Price - [SUM1]
FROM @OrderDetails AS A
LEFT JOIN @Item AS R ON A.ItemId = R.Id
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(SUB1.TOTAL) AS [SUM1]
    FROM @OrderDetails AS SUB1
    WHERE SUB1.ItemId = A.ItemId AND SUB1.OrderId <= A.OrderId
) AS B
```